# How do I make Ruby's Array difference (minus) method, `Array#-`, work with my classes?

Tags: ruby

I think the best way to explain this is with an example:

```
class A
    attr_accessor :test
    def initialize(x = nil)
        @test = x
    end

    def ==(other)
        return @test == other.test
    end
end

a1 = A.new(1) # => #<A:0x11b7118 @test=1>
a1.test # => 1

a2 = A.new(1) # => #<A:0x11fb0f8 @test=1>
a2.test # => 1

a1 == a2 # => true
[a1].include?(a2) # => true
[a1] - [a2] # => [#<A:0x11b7118 @test=1>]
```

In this example, how would I get [a1] - [a2] to return an empty array, as one would expect it to for any other Ruby class? Is there some method that I have to define for A that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override `eql?` and `hash`. These are the ones that are used for those kinds of *set operations*.

Comment: Ah, I knew it had to be something simple like that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Add these methods to A

```
def eql?(other)
  @test == other.test
end

def hash
  @test.hash
end
```

Comment: If I override the hash method that way, will the fact that `a.hash == 1.hash` cause any problems?

Comment: Not really, the only requirement of a hash code is that if the instances are equal, it has to return the same value.

If you're planning on having both ints and A's in the same array though, you'd need to check that other is an A before calling other.test.